# Understanding an overloaded operator[] example

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, overloading, binary-operators

I am confused with a question that I saw in a c++ test.
The code is here:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Int {
public:
    int v;
    Int(int a) { v = a; }
    Int &operator[](int x) {
        v+=x;
        return *this;
    }
};
ostream &operator<< (ostream &o, Int &a) {
    return o << a.v;
}

int main() {
    Int i = 2;
    cout << i[0] << i[2]; //why does it print 44 ?
    return 0;
}
```

I was kinda sure that this would print `24` but instead it prints `44`. I would really like someone to clarify this. Is it a cumulative evaluation?
Also is the `<<` **binary infix** ?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: *in case of not well defined operator overload, could someone give a better implementation of the overloaded operators here so it would print `24`?*

Comment: `cout << i[0] << i[2];` could also be written like this:  `operator<<(operator<<(cout, i[0]), i[2]);`

Comment: it seems the order of evaluation of two << is not well defined. Debug your code and you will see the i[2] is called first.

Comment: I'd really suggest against making `operator[]` have side effects. I think that behavior is going to bite you again at some point and not just here. Imagine how that interacts with multithreading, e.g.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This program has indeterminate behavior: the compiler is not required to evaluate `i[0]` and `i[2]` in a left-to-right order (the C++ language gives this freedom to compilers in order to allow for optimizations).

For instance, [Clang does it in this instance](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ace14e8eff32651), while [GCC does not](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bf93169cae91085).

The order of evaluation is unspecified, so you cannot expect a consistent output, not even when running your program repeatedly on a specific machine.

If you wanted to get consistent output, you could rephrase the above as follows (or in some equivalent way):

```
cout << i[0];
cout << i[2];
```

As you can see, GCC [no longer outputs `44`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07b0f3e1545b7ec1) in this case.

**EDIT:**

If, for whatever reason, you really really want the expression `cout << i[0] << i[2]` to print `24`, you will have to modify the definition of the overloaded operators (`operator []` and `operator <<`) significantly, because the language intentionally makes it impossible to tell which subexpression (`i[0]` or `[i2]`) gets evaluated first.

The only guarantee you get here is that the result of evaluating `i[0]` is going to be inserted into `cout` before the result of evaluating `i[2]`, so your best bet is probably to let `operator <<` perform the modification of `Int's` data member `v`, rather than `operator []`.

However, the delta that should be applied to `v` is passed as an argument to `operator []`, and you need some way of forwarding it to `operator <<` together with the original `Int` object. One possibility is to let `operator []` return a data structure that contains the delta as well as a reference to the original object:

```
class Int;

struct Decorator {
    Decorator(Int& i, int v) : i{i}, v{v} { }
    Int& i;
    int v;
};

class Int {
public:
    int v;
    Int(int a) { v = a; }
    Decorator operator[](int x) {
        return {*this, x}; // This is C++11, equivalent to Decorator(*this, x)
    }
};
```

Now you just need to rewrite `operator <<` so that it accepts a `Decorator` object, modifies the referenced `Int` object by applying the stored delta to the `v` data member, then prints its value:

```
ostream &operator<< (ostream &o, Decorator const& d) {
    d.i.v += d.v;
    o << d.i.v;
    return o;
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8658b949c1c80a3).

*Disclaimer*: As others have mentioned, keep in mind that `operator []` and `operator <<` are typically non-mutating operations (more precisely, they do not mutate the state of the object which is indexed and stream-inserted, respectively), so you are highly discouraged from writing code like this unless you're just trying to solve some C++ trivia.

Comment: @vsoftco: The behavior is not undefined in this case, only indeterminate. Calls to overloaded `operator []` are just regular function calls and they cannot interleave (see paragraph 1.9/15)

Comment: Hmm, but the par. ends with: *if a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, and they are not potentially concurrent (1.10), the behavior is undefined.* I am a bit confused, isn't the `operator[]` a "side effect"? Ohh ok ok, I missed the part after the example. Thanks!

Comment: @vsoftco: Right, footnote 9 also clarifies a bit: "*In other words, function executions do not interleave with each other*."

Comment: @AndyProwl Thanks for the answer. I have already tried what you proposed with the 2 `cout` How would we overload the `<<` so it could print `24`? Thanks again, I also made an edit in the original post as well.

Comment: @vsoftco Maybe rewriting the expression as `operator<<(operator<<(cout, i.operator[](0)), i.operator[](2));` will make it easier to understand. The two calls to `operator[]` can happen in any order, but they will not interleave, which makes the modifications to `v` indeterminately sequenced, not unsequenced.

Comment: @Praetorian Thanks, I understand how the call works, I was just unsure about the function non-interleaving behaviour.

Comment: @GeoPapas: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want `cout << i[0] << i[2];` to print `24`?

Comment: @AndyProwl Yes, if that is possible at all.

Answer (score 5):

To explain what's going on here, let's make things much simpler: `cout<<2*2+1*1;`.  What happens first, 2*2 or 1*1?  One possible answer is 2*2 should happen first, since it's the leftmost thing.  But the C++ standard says: who cares?!  After all, the result is 5 either way.  But sometimes it matters.  For instance, if `f` and `g` are two functions, and we do `f()+g()`, then there is no guarantee which gets called first.  If `f` prints a message, but `g` exits the program, then the message may never be printed.  In your case, `i[2]` got called before `i[0]`, because C++ thinks it doesn't matter.  You have two choices:

One option is to change your code so it doesn't matter.  Rewrite your `[]` operator so that it doesn't change the `Int`, and returns a fresh `Int` instead.  This is probably a good idea anyway, since that will make it consistent with 99% of all the other `[]` operators on the planet.  It also requires less code:

`Int &operator[](int x) { return this->v + x;}`.

Your other option is to keep your `[]` the same, and split your printing into two statements:

`cout<<i[0]; cout<<i[2];`

Some languages actually do guarantee that in `2*2+1*1`, the 2*2 is done first.  But not C++.

Edit: I was not as clear as I hoped.  Let's try more slowly.  There are two ways for C++ to evaluate `2*2+1*1`.

Method 1: `2*2+1*1 ---> 4+1*1 ---> 4+1 --->5`.

Method 2: `2*2+1*1 ---> 2*2+1 ---> 4+1 --->5`.

In both cases we get the same answer.

Let's try this again with a different expression: `i[0]+i[2]`.

Method 1: `i[0]+i[2] ---> 2+i[2] ---> 2+4 ---> 6`.

Method 2: `i[0]+i[2] ---> i[0]+4 ---> 4+4 ---> 8`.

We got a different answer, because the `[]` has side effects, so it matters whether we do `i[0]` or `i[2]` first.  According to C++, these are both valid answers.  Now, we are ready to attack your original problem.  As you will soon see, it has almost nothing to do with the `<<` operator.

How does C++ deal with `cout << i[0] << i[2]`?  As before, there are two choices.

Method 1: `cout << i[0] << i[2] ---> cout << 2 << i[2] ---> cout << 2 << 4`.

Method 2: `cout << i[0] << i[2] ---> cout << i[0] << 4 ---> cout << 4 << 4`.

The first method will print 24 like you expected.  But according to C++, method 2 is equally good, and it will print 44 like you saw.  Notice that the trouble happens before the `<<` gets called.  There is no way to overload `<<` to prevent this, because by the time `<<` is running, the "damage" has already been done.

Comment: +1 for mentioning how utterly stupid the [] method here is (and other stuff mentioned too!) Because... I've never seen that use before!

Comment: @MarkVY hello Mark. Where did you read that c++ doesnt have a priority in operators? `*` operator has higher priority than `+`. In any case, the problem in this code sample is not in the subscript operator `[ ]` implentation but in`<<`.

Comment: @GeoPapas I think you misread this answer. C++ does have priority in operators and `*` has higher priority than `+`, this answer assumes you know that already.  Perhaps you are mixing up priority with order of evaluation.

Comment: `2*2 + 1*1` is a bit of an unclear example though, since in reality the compiler would just substitute `5`. I'd suggest changing it to only use the `f() + g()` example.